# Get data from url using Jsoup : No data retrieved

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get data from this URL:

http://fr.news.yahoo.com/jo-sotchi-manifestations-monde-entier-contre-loi-russe-125051858.html

I am using the `JSoup` library to get the value of a DOM element.

But I don't recieve any response. Here is my code :

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String urldisplay = params[0];
    Log.d("INFO", "URL : "+urldisplay);
    String source = params[1];
    String toSet = null;
    String articleToDisplay = null ;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(urldisplay)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0")
                .timeout(0)
                    .get();
        toSet = doc.select("div.mediaarticlebody").text() ;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
        return toSet;               
}
```

Comment: I just hope that there's actually something else than `String... params` in your code :)

Comment: Post the exact exception and the stacktrace

Comment: There is no exception, the result in toSet variable is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the site isn't recognising the user agent. It works for me if I change the userAgent as follows:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://fr.news.yahoo.com/jo-sotchi-manifestations-monde-entier-contre-loi-russe-125051858.html")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36")
                .timeout(0).get();

Element el = doc.select("div#mediaarticlebody").first();
System.out.println(el);
```

Outputs:

```
<div class="yom-mod yom-art-content " id="mediaarticlebody" itemprop="articleBody">
 <div class="bd">
  <!-- google_ad_section_start -->
  <p class="first"><strong>MONDE - A deux jours de la c&eacute;r&eacute;monie d'ouverture, des rassemblements sont pr&eacute;vus dans le monde entier contre cette loi pass&eacute;e 2012...</strong></p> 
  <p>Les Jeux olympiques de Sotchi ouvrent une fen&ecirc;tre de tir sans pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent pour d&eacute;noncer de nouveau la loi &laquo;anti-gay&raquo; adopt&eacute;e en juin 2012 en Russie, selon les d&eacute;fenseurs des droits de l'Homme et les organisations LGBT (lesbiennes, gays, bisexuels, transsexuels). A deux jours de la c&eacute;r&eacute;monie d'ouverture, des rassemblements sont pr&eacute;vus dans le monde entier contre cette loi, qui punit d'une amende pouvant atteindre 500.000 roubles (10.600 euros environ) &nbsp;et de prison la &laquo;propagande&raquo; homosexuelle devant mineurs.</p> 
  <p>&laquo;C'est le moment de pousser les sponsors [des JO] &agrave; utiliser leur pouvoir &eacute;conomique, afin d'appeler &agrave; l'abrogation de ces lois discriminatoires&raquo;, &eacute;crit l'ONG de d&eacute;fense LGBT All Out sur son site, les appelant &agrave; &laquo;sortir de leur silence sur les lois anti-gay russes&raquo;. Elle organise des manifestations dans 19 villes du monde, de New York &agrave; Melbourne en passant par Paris et Saint-P&eacute;tersbourg pour la Russie - mais pas Sotchi.</p> 
  <p><b>Agressions homophobes</b></p> 
  <p>Vladimir Poutine avait promulgu&eacute; cette loi controvers&eacute;e en juin 2012, ouvrant la voie &agrave; une vague d'agressions homophobes en Russie. Le texte avait suscit&eacute; des appels au boycott des jeux Olympiques de Sotchi. En janvier 2013, Amnesty International avait d&eacute;nonc&eacute; une loi &laquo;&eacute;tabli[ssant] une discrimination &agrave; l'&eacute;gard des personnes LGBT&raquo;, &laquo;aliment[ant] les discours homophobes&raquo; et &laquo;encourag[eant] la stigmatisation en entretenant l'id&eacute;e que les enfants doivent &ecirc;tre prot&eacute;g&eacute;s contre l'homosexualit&eacute;&raquo;. L'ONG rappelait aussi que &laquo;certains d&eacute;fenseurs des droits des personnes LGBT [avaient] d&eacute;j&agrave; &eacute;t&eacute; harcel&eacute;s et agress&eacute;s&raquo;.</p> 
  <p>De son c&ocirc;t&eacute;, le pr&eacute;sident am&eacute;ricain Barack Obama a indiqu&eacute; en septembre dernier qu'il n'avait &laquo;aucune patience pour les pays qui cherchaient &agrave; intimider ou nuire aux gays, lesbiennes ou les transsexuels&raquo;. La d&eacute;l&eacute;gation (...) <a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.20minutes.fr/article/1290686/ynews1290686?xtor=RSS-176"><strong>Lire la suite sur 20minutes.fr</strong><br /><br /></a><a href="http://www.20minutes.fr/monde/libye/1290674-20140205-libye-six-enfants-blesses-engin-explosif-ecole?xtor=RSS-176" rel="nofollow">Libye: attentat &agrave; la bombe dans une &eacute;cole &agrave; Benghazi, 12 enfants bless&eacute;s</a><br /><a href="http://www.20minutes.fr/monde/1290678-20140205-onu-presse-vatican-deferer-pedophiles-a-justice?xtor=RSS-176" rel="nofollow">L'ONU presse le Vatican de d&eacute;f&eacute;rer les p&eacute;dophiles &agrave; la justice</a><br /><a href="http://www.20minutes.fr/monde/irak/1290374-20140205-irak-sept-morts-attentats-a-bagdad?xtor=RSS-176" rel="nofollow">Irak: 24 morts dans de nouveaux attentats &agrave; Bagdad</a><br /><a href="http://www.20minutes.fr/monde/russie/1290610-20140205-jo-2014-flamme-a-sotchi-manifestations-monde?xtor=RSS-176" rel="nofollow">JO-2014: la flamme &agrave; Sotchi, des manifestations dans le monde</a><br /><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.backelite.vingtminutes&amp;hl=fr" rel="nofollow">T&eacute;l&eacute;chargez gratuitement l'application Android 20 Minutes</a><br /></p> 
  <!-- google_ad_section_end -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze the page, you'll see that `div.mediaarticlebody` doesn't exist. There is no `div` with class `mediaarticlebody`. Instead, there is a div with **id** `mediaarticlebody`, so your selection should be

```
div#mediaarticlebody
```

Comment: Oups, yes good point. I tried with your advice and i don't get any content.